# Not getting value from scope, getting error : Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("Main", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", [ function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 545
}]);` 
var app = angular.module("Main", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", [ function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 545
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You DI is wrong, you need to add `$scope` both as argument and list into the array.

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 545
}]);
```

Or you have to do this:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 545
});
```

The first one is recommanded because the second one works only for unminified code.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is not correct. Try this.

```
 var app = angular.module("Main", []);

    app.controller("MainCtrl", [ "$scope", function ($scope) {
      $scope.value = 545
    }]);
```